# Why is my data not being stored in the session variable?

Tags: php, session

I'm having problems getting reading my HTML inputs and storing the data in session variables, the end goal is to have this data inserted into a MySQL table, so if there's a better way of doing it, that would be appreciated as well :)

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Blog space </title>
    <head>
    <body bgcolor = "EAEAEA">
        <h4> Register </h4>
        <form form method = "post" action = "InsertToDatabase.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style = "color:#0080c0;font-weight:bold">Register</legend>
                <table> 
                    <tr>
                        <td> Name: </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "text" name = "myName"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                                
                        <td> Surname: </td>
                        <td> 
                            <input type = "text" name = "mySurname"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Gender: </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "text" name = "myGender"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Date of birth: </td>
                        <td> 
                            <input type = "date" name = "myDateOfBirth"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Email: </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "email" name = "myEmail"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td> Contact: </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "text" name = "myContact">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input style="background-color:#46A5F9;
                            color:white; width:19mm"
                            type = "submit"
                            value = "Submit"/>                                  
            </fieldset>                 
        </form>   
    </body>
    <?php                       
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['myName'];;
        $_SESSION['surname'] = $_POST['mySurname'];
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['myGender'];
        $_SESSION['dob'] = $_POST['myDateOfBirth'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['myEmail'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['myContact'];         
    ?> 
</html>
```

This is my code, feel free to let me know if I left any important details out.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to store it in a session first, before writing to the database? If the page isn’t initially accessed with a POST, you should be receiving an error at the bottom about an undefined array key.

Comment: I'm using a session variable because the function that writes it to the db is on another page, the page referenced by the method action

Comment: and yes, I am receiving that error

Comment: You're posting your form to `InsertToDatabase.php`, `$_POST` will never be set on the page you posted

Comment: The lines at the bottom that set the session variables will fail if the page is loaded using GET. The form `action` points to `InsertToDatabase.php` - is that **this** page/script or another?